# Error in getSparkSession() : SparkSession not initialized

Tags: r, sparkr

I ran a single line of code to make a Spark DataFrame. I installed SparkR and used library(SparkR) before I ran the following:

```
spark_df <- as.DataFrame(data)
```

However I get the following error message

> Error in getSparkSession() : SparkSession not initialized

What do I need to do?

Comment: use create data frame method.

Comment: I get the same error even when I use createDataFrame() method

Answer (score 0):

This is for Databricks using R notebooks.  Make sure you load the library. This loads the diamonds dataset which if famous for linear regression.

Refer to docs for details.  https://docs.databricks.com/sparkr/overview.html

```
library(SparkR)
diamondsDF <- read.df("/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", source = "csv", header="true", inferSchema = "true")
head(diamondsDF)
```

There is code to create a spark data frame also.

```
library(SparkR)
df <- createDataFrame(faithful)

# Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
head(df)
```

Comment: createDataFrame() gives me the same error

Comment: What environment are you using?  So many flavors of Spark ...

Answer (score 0):

It must be your environment.

Here is the output from the second block of code.

[image]

Here is the output from the first block of code.

[image]

Another syntax that works fine.

[image]

Are you using R-Studio and spark is not local?  Read the docs on how to connect.  Databricks does this automatically for you!

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html

Comment: Yea, there was an issue with my environment variables

Comment: please up tick the answer.  It was not R, it was your environment.